# WebLogic server taking old EAR despite restart

Tags: deployment, ear, weblogic8.x

i am running a WebLogic 8.1 application server, despite restarts it is taking my old EAR file, is there a way to flush the old file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its weblogic 8.1, please delete the `.wldonotdelete` directory under weblogic server directory and restart your servers.

If it weblogic 9.2 and above version please go to server directory and delete tmp directory under server and restart your server.